# how to use InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions make navigator transitions faster

Tags: ios, react-native, navigator

Because of complex logic, I have to render many components when `this.props.navigator.push()`, slow navigator transitions make app unavailable.

[image]

then I notice [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#slow-navigator-transitions) provide `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` api to solve this problem,

I need bring most of components which consumed long time to callback after navigator animation finished, but I don't know where should I call it,

maybe a simple example is enough,

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's a full example of what a performant [`Navigator`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) scene might look like:

```js
import {Component} from 'react';
import {InteractionManager, Text} from 'react-native';

class OptimizedScene extends Component {

  state = {interactionsComplete: false};

  componentDidMount() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.setState({interactionsComplete: true});
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.interactionsComplete) {
      return <Text>loading...</Text>;
    }

    return (
      <ExpensiveComponent/>
    );
  }
}
```

This has been extracted into [a library](https://github.com/jshanson7/react-native-interactions) to make it even easier:

```js
import {AfterInteractions} from 'react-native-interactions';

function MyScene() {
  return (
    <AfterInteractions placeholder={<CheapPlaceholder/>}>
      <ExpensiveComponent/>
    </AfterInteractions>
  );
}
```

Comment: So i tried to do the same thing, but it is not working. What i realised is the callback function provided to the interactionManager gets called after a component is fully loaded (which we want) but after setting the conditional rendering, it gets called immediately thus putting not effect. How can we use it properly

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#slow-navigator-transitions

There you can find an example of how to implement placeholders to get faster transitions!

Comment: I suspect what you intended to link isn't there anymore, because I saw the example once upon a time.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass any code that is keeping the JS thread busy to the InteractionManager, e.g.

```
InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    someLongTask() // or animations, or whatever
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {InteractionManager} from "react-native"; 

componentDidMount() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.setState({renderPlaceholderOnly: false});
    });
  }
```

Reference : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#slow-navigator-transitions